# Is there a standards-compliant alternative to boost interval_map?

Tags: c++, boost, c++14, c++17

I have a C++ code base that was finished in 2010. It uses the `boost::interval_map`. However, I would like to eliminate the dependency on boost and make it just use C++14 or (if I must) C++17.

Is there an way to get the functionality of the boost interval_map under C++14 or C++17 without having to simply reimplement the boost class?

Comment: Why do you think it wouldn't be possible to implement `interval_map` in C++ when it is clearly written in C++? Or are you asking if the C++ standard library has such a type?

Comment: There's no dedicated interval tree in the standard library. While both interval trees and `std::map` are (usually but not formally) based on red-black trees, I don't think there's a way to build an interval tree on top of a built-in container, at least efficiently. Here's a single-header interval tree that appears to let you attach data to intervals if that helps:
https://github.com/ekg/intervaltree

Comment: I don't believe C++14 or C++17 have added any such data structure. If you don't care about supporting ancient compilers, you could write a simpler implementation than boost's.

Comment: I clarified my question.

Comment: @parktomatomi - that's great. If you make it an answer, I can accept it.